# Background fullscreen slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm searching for fulscreen background slideshow in any resolution. I've found solutions with fixed size. Is it possible to make slideshow with fade effect (and resize (fit) images to full screen) in background?

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/

http://nanotux.com/blog/fullscreen/

https://github.com/bigfolio/jQuery-Backgrounder

And a slider http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Google is great :)

Comment: i want something like that http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/fade.html without any button, loader ...